# Why is my php curl script timing out?

Tags: php, mysql, loops, curl, proxy

I have the bellow code that takes input of urls and proxies from textarea fields, uses curl to take the source code, takes certain links from the pages and inserts them into a database. This worked for one url, but does not work after I added proxies and two loops for multiple urls/proxies. Now it just times out with no error message and says it cannot find the file. i am getting proxies from proxy-list.org. Any pointers will be appreciated.

```
<html>
<body>

<?
$urls=explode("\n", $_POST['url']);
$proxies=explode("\n", $_POST['proxy']);

$allurls=count($urls);
$allproxies=count($proxies);

for ( $counter = 0; $counter <= $allurls; $counter++) {
for ( $count = 0; $count <= $allproxies; $count++) {

 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$urls[$counter]);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 0);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY,$proxies[$count]);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST,'GET');
 curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); 
 curl_exec ($ch); 
 $curl_scraped_page=curl_exec($ch); 

//use the new tool box
require "ToolBoxA4.php";

//call the new function parseA1
$arrOut = parseA1 ($curl_scraped_page);

//the output is an array with 3 items:  $arrOut[0] is RHS, $arrOut[1] is TOP, $arrOut[2] is NAT
//to look at the RHS

//$arrLookAt = explode(",", $arrOut[0]);
//print_r ($arrLookAt);
//echo "<br><hr><br>";
//foreach ($arrLookAt as $value){
//       echo $value;
//       echo "<br>";
//}

$FileName = abs(rand(0,1000000000000));
$FileHandle = fopen($FileName, 'w') or die("can't open file");
fwrite($FileHandle, $curl_scraped_page);

//$dom = new DOMDocument();
//@$dom->loadHTML($curl_scraped_page);
//$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
//$hrefs = $xpath->query('//a[@href][@id]');

$hostname="****";
$username="****";
$password="****";
$dbname="****";
$usertable="****";

$con=mysql_connect($hostname,$username, $password) or die ("<html><script language='JavaScript'>alert('Unable to connect to database! Please try again later.'),history.go(-1)</script></html>");
mysql_select_db($dbname ,$con);

//function storeLink($url) {
//  $query = "INSERT INTO **** (time, ad1, ad2) VALUES ('$FileName','$url', '$gathered_from')";
//  mysql_query($query) or die('Error, insert query failed');
//}
//for ($i = 0; $i < $hrefs->length; $i++) {
//  $href = $hrefs->item($i);
//  $url = $href->getAttribute('href');
//  storeLink($url);
//
//}

//function storeLink($top, $right) {
//$query = "INSERT INTO happyturtle (time, ad1, ad2) VALUES ('$FileName','$top', '$right')";
//mysql_query($query) or die('Error, insert query failed');

$right = explode(",", $arrOut[0]);
$top = explode(",", $arrOut[1]);

for ( $countforme = 0; $countforme <= 5; $countforme++) {

$topnow=$top[$countforme];

$query = "INSERT INTO **** (time, ad1) VALUES ('$FileName','$topnow')";
mysql_query($query) or die('Error, insert query failed');

}

for ( $countforme = 0; $countforme <= 15; $countforme++) {

$rightnow = $right[$countforme];


$query = "INSERT INTO **** (time, ad1) VALUES ('$FileName','$rightnow')";
mysql_query($query) or die('Error, insert query failed');

}


mysql_close($con);

fclose($FileHandle);

curl_close($ch);

//echo $FileName; 

//echo "<br/>";

}
}

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code will get each of the URLs in sequence so it can take a long time to run.  One possible solution is to use the cURL "multi" interface that allows multiple requests to run simultaneously - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php

Another alternative would be to increase the PHP timeout on the server you are using if this is essentially a batch process.  Info on this is at http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

One observation I would make is that public proxies (such as those from proxy-list.org) can be very slow to respond and since you are requesting from multiple locations your script will always take as long as the slowest proxy takes to respond (which may be longer than your server's PHP timeout setting).